# open source language translation engine

Tags: translation

have you worked on language translation. are there good libraries available for the same or will i have to deal with most of the things myself.

Comment: What's wrong with http://translate.google.com/ ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this [**Apertium**](http://www.apertium.org/) it's still active and can translate between multiple languages.
 You can also check Wikipedia for more info and diverse resources [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apertium) .

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks Qantas 94 Heavy, I guess Wikipedia can do more on that!